# what should be the frequency distribution of the eigenvalues of a randomly generated hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, random

I'm getting the eigenvalues of a randomly generated hermitian matrix distributed like a normal probabilistic distribution(crowded in the middle values )
but my sir told me that it should be a semicircle , not a bell shaped one.

(not enough rep to upload the plot image, sorry)

Comment: You can upload the image to imgur.com, post a link to the image, and somebody else can attach it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were told wrong. The values should indeed approach the semicircle law, but only when the size goes to infinity (and I think that you need some control on the variance of the entries, but I don't really recall that now).

Comment: so it means if i increase the size of the matrix (now is 100*100) it can approach to semicircle law?

Comment: In the limit, which doesn't necessarily mean you can get it in practice. Try searching for "Wigner law".

Comment: this graph is for a 5000x5000 matrix http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html